# React native redux stacknavigation issue: View not getting loaded

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I am new to redux. I wanted to implement redux with my react-native application. Here is my code.

Application getting initialized from index.android.js

```
render() {
    return (
  <View>
    <RootComponent />
  </View>
 );
}
```

Root component is the component/container where i am initializing my stacknavigator.

```
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
Login: { screen: LoginContainer },
App: { screen: AppContainer }
},
{
    headerMode: 'none'
}
);

const navReducer = (state, action) => {
  const nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
  return nextState || state;
};

const appReducer = combineReducers({
  nav: navReducer
});

class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <AppNavigator navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
            dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
            state: this.props.nav,
        }) } />
    );
}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  nav: state.nav
});

const AppWithNavigationState = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);

const store = createStore(appReducer);

export default class RootComponent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <AppWithNavigationState />
        </Provider>
    );
}
}
```

As per my navigation, i should go to the login component/container. The container is as following:

```
export default class LoginContainer extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    alert('In login component');
}

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>
                Login Screen
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

After running the code, i could see the alert written inside my Login component's constructor function. Although, neither the view is visible on the emulator, nor its showing any error.

Can anyone help me for the same.

Comment: Please see my question on github. I have asked if I should integrate redux to react-navigator or not. https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/2003   The answer is no. So IMO you should not try to integrate. No benefits to do this, plus you will lose time.

Comment: @FurkanO : Thanks for your reply. Even i was not sure whether to use it or not. This post helped. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add style to both of your parent `<View>` tags like this `<View style={{flex: 1}}>` which act as a wrapper to all your JSX inside `index.android.js` and `LoginContainer`.

Your `<View>`s are essentially not visible on the screen since they're devoid of any height and width.

Hope it helps!